# passing multiple arguments to function annyang (not just voice commands)

Tags: javascript, voice-recognition, annyang

I am trying to pass two arguments to my function fill_node:
1) a named-variable and 
2) the data type such as mm, kg, etc.
Since mm, milimeter are the same, i grouped them into one data type and passed it as the argument, `entry type` to the function: `fill_node(entry,entry_type)`

however the browser gives the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tag1 is not defined
    at print.js:57
```

Here is my command code:

```
var material = {
    ':tag1 mm':fill_node(0),
    ':tag2 millimeter':fill_node(0)
}
var weight = {
    ':tag3 kg':fill_node(tag3,1),
    ':tag4 kilo':fill_node(tag4,1),
    ':tag5 kilogram':fill_node(tag5,1)
};
```